# ¿Como evitar ECONNRESET?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy desarrollando un aplicación web en la que interactúo con el API de ebay. Necesito obtener las políticas de usuario mediante peticiones al API. Lo que he hecho ha sido crear un método para cada una, en este caso serían 3 métodos, y finalmente uno que llama a todos mediante "request/request-promise". El caso es que para realzar esas llamadas necesito un token de autorización el cual ya puedo obtener. 
Antes de realizar las llamadas a los 3 endpoints de los que voy a obtener las políticas existe otra función con la cual compruebo si el token a expirado, lo cual hace cada dos horas, y como consecuencia tienes que usar el "refresh_token" para hacer otra petición al API de ebay para refrescar ese token.
El caso es que cuando no tengo que refrescar el token las 3 llamadas se realizan con total normalidad, pero si se necesita refrescar solo realiza la llamada a al endpoint de refresco del token y luego no sigue, llega a entrar en la funciones de llamada a las politicas, pero en la primera se queda parado ya. El caso es que cuando consulto la consola de POSTMAN me viene el error ECONNRESET y las cabeceras vacías.

Aqui se hacen las llamadas al chequeo del token y a continuación al resto:

```
async function getAllPolicies(req, res, next) {
        try {
            /*Más codigo, a contiación se realizan las llamadas*/
            await checkTokenExpiration(ebShop.creationDate, ebShop.expirationDate, shopName);
            let returnPolicies = await requestP(baseUrl + `getReturnPolicies/${shopName}`);
            let returnPJSON = JSON.parse(returnPolicies);
            let paymentPolicies = await requestP(baseUrl + `getPaymentPolicies/${shopName}`);
            let paymentPJSON = JSON.parse(paymentPolicies);
            let fulfillmentPolicies = await requestP(baseUrl + `getFulfillmentPolicies/${shopName}`);
            let fulfillmentPJSON = JSON.parse(fulfillmentPolicies);
            let allPolicies = { return: returnPJSON.returnPolicies, fulfillment: fulfillmentPJSON.fulfillmentPolicies, payment: paymentPJSON.paymentPolicies };
            return res.status(200).send(allPolicies);
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    }
```

Aquí es donde se comprueba el token:

```
async function checkTokenExpiration(creationDate, expirationDate, shopName) {
    try {
        let exp = moment(expirationDate);
        let cre = moment(creationDate);
        let diff = exp.diff(cre, 'minutes');
        if (diff >= 120) {
            console.log("El token ha expirado y debe ser renovado.");
            await requestP.post(baseUrl + `/refreshEbayToken/${shopName}`);//Aquí se hace la llamda al endpoint con el que renuevo el token.
        } else {
            console.log(`Quedan ${120 - dif} minutos para que expire el token.`);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

Función que refresca el token:

```
async function refreshToken(req, res, next) {

    /*Aquí hay código pero irrelevante en lo que el problema se refiere*/

    try {
        let result = await requestP.post(reqOptions);
        let resultJSON = JSON.parse(result);
        let access_token = resultJSON.access_token;
        let acces_token_expires = resultJSON.expires_in;
        let date_token_exp = moment().add(acces_token_expires, 'seconds');
        let dateToday = moment();
        let shopsConfigFile = await utils.readShopsFile();
        let shopFromFile = shopsConfigFile.filter(s => s.name == shopName)[0];
        shopFromFile.oAuthToken = access_token;
        shopFromFile.oAuthExpires = date_token_exp;
        shopFromFile.creationDate = dateToday;
        await utils.writeShopsFile(shopsConfigFile);
        return res.send({ ack: true, result: result });
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

Después de ejecutarse el refresco del token todo sigue, hasta que entra en el primer método de obtención de politicas y una vez ejecuta el "request" se para, cosa que si no hay que refrescar token no pasa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado donde se genera el error. Al estar con "nodemon" activo en el entorno de desarrollo, cada cambio en cualquiera de los ficheros que componen la aplicación va a ser controlado por Nodemon, reiniciando el servidor. En un momento del proceso, escribo en unos archivos mediante la dependencia "File System" promisificándo tanto "writeFile" como "readFile". Entonces una vez escribe en los ficheros la aplicación entera se reinicia. Cuando Nodemon no está activo todo transcurre de forma normal puesto que no hay nada "vigilando" los cambios en el código.